# Last Bootstrap tooltip doesn't work

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-2

This is my HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr class="primary">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>
            <a data-toogle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Add user" href="#/tutoria/add/1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon-lg **tooltips** add-user" data-original-title="Agregar usuario"></a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
    <--!The last tooltip that I've in my table (tr) doesn't work-->
    <tr class="primary">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>
            <a data-toogle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Add user" href="#/tutoria/add/2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon-lg **tooltips** add-user"></a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The JS code:

```
$(".tooltips").tooltip();
```

I'm implementing Bootstrap with Backbone and I've this problem: all the tooltips (Bootstrap) work fine, unless the tooltips that I've in the last row of the table.

Comment: Maybe you don't see it because of the bottom placement. Perhaps there is something above it. Change the placement to top to discard that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added

```
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>
```

below bootstrap.min.js and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The last tooltip in the table is missing the `data-original-title` tag. You have included this in the first tooltip, which is why that one is working.

Change your code from:

`<a data-toogle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Add user" href="#/tutoria/add/2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon-lg **tooltips** add-user">`

to:

`<a data-toogle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Add user" href="#/tutoria/add/2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon-lg **tooltips** add-user" data-original-title="tooltipcontenthere">`

Answer (score 0):

The code that you are giving , should work and it works , i tried it on chrome , firefox , IE , i can copy u the code but it is same as yours , unless there is another code before the last tr with quotes not closed which prevent jquery to recognize the last 'a' as part of ".tooltips" selector

```
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(".tooltips").tooltip();
        </script>
<html>
<body>

<table>
    <tr class="primary">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>
            <a data-toogle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Add user" href="#/tutoria/add/1" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon-lg **tooltips** add-user" data-original-title="Agregar usuario"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <--!The last tooltip that I've in my table (tr) doesn't work-->
    <tr class="primary">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>
            <a data-toogle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Add user" href="#/tutoria/add/2" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus glyphicon-lg **tooltips** add-user"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

use the chrome debugger to know if when you use the selector '.tooltips' is jquery selecting the last 'a' ?